# pgfplots /.append overwrites tikz plot arguments

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Summary: I have troubles with pgfplots and tikz in understanding which option(s) overwrite each other and which have the highest priority.

In the following code, the arguments `mark size=6pt` and `mark repeat=1` within the `\addplot[...]` arguments will be ignored, as they were already altered by using an `[...]/.append style[...]` command. I just don't understand why append locks those commands - even when trying to change these later...

Here's the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots,grffile,amsmath}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\pgfplotscreateplotcyclelist{markerlist4}{%
mark=square\\%
mark=o\\%
mark=diamond\\%
mark=halfsquare*\\%
}

\pgfplotsset{every axis plot/.append style={
       every mark/.append style={mark color=none, solid, line join=miter, line width=0.5pt, mark size=2pt, mark repeat=100000}
    },}

\pgfplotsset{/pgfplots/width=7.5cm}
\pgfplotsset{/pgfplots/height=5.6cm}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
xmin=0,
xmax=1,
ymin=0,
ymax=1,
cycle list name=markerlist4,
]
\addplot+[color=black, line width=1.0pt, mark phase=4, mark size=6pt, mark repeat=1]
coordinates{(0,0)(0.1,0.1)(0.2,0.2)(0.3,0.3)(0.4,0.4)(0.5,0.5)(0.6,0.6)};
\addlegendentry{mark options={}}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result looks like this:

### [image: arguments are ignored]

If I add a `mark options={}` to the `\addplot[...]` arguments, all of the `/.append style` arguments get deleted and the `mark size=6pt` and also `mark repeat=1` will not be ignored., e.g.:

```
 \addplot+[color=black, line width=1.0pt, mark phase=4, mark size=6pt, mark repeat=1, mark options={}]
```

Now the result looks like this:

[image: Now the arguments are not ignored...]

So it seems as if the `every axis plot... append` command locks the arguments (specifically the `mark size` in this case) until released by `mark options={}` within the `addplot` argument list. Why is that? Is that intended?

---

The problem is that I am using many customization commands such as the `\pgfplotsset{every axis plot/.append style= ... ...}` because I like to have suiting default style settings, which I need to customize for very specific plots only (unfortunately a lot more often than I hoped) but I don't get behind the concept of priorization of arguments/commands within pgfplots and tikz. It took me like ages to find out what I just posted - I failed to google it - and I stumble upon similar issues regularily. It's always the same problem: why is a specific option ignored or (secretly) overwritten,... For example I don't understand the kind of equality of some commands: e.g. `\pgfplotsset{every axis plot/.append style={every mark/.append style={mark size=2pt}}}` seems to be more or less the same as `mark options={mark size=2pt}`, but can both be used independently of the environment, e.g. inside and outside the tikzpicture and are both really equal or is there a difference?

So my specific question is why arguments within the `\addplot+[...]` arguments seem to have no effect as they are obviously overwritten by some `pgfplotsset APPEND` commands (which were set prior!), of which I though that these are only **appended** to the default settings and should be easily overwritten if specified differently...

But the general question is if someone can explain to me the concept behind it a little further - hoping that I will realize a 'mistake' I do more quickly next time, as it is so annoying to google 5 hours for every second tikzspicture...

PS: I have even a subsequent question related to the priorization of commands problem: If I want to specifiy an option like the marker line width within the argument of the `\addplot[...]` command: How can I realize this without using `mark options={...}`, which will unfortunately delete/reset all other mark options that have been appended before if those are not also copied into the argument again (the problem is that a command like `line width` is already reserved for the plots/graphs line and one doesn't necessarily always wants marker lines and plot/graph lines have the same line width)? `marker line width=2pt` will result in an error as it is not a known argument.

Comment: It seems as if nobody knows a solution. I guess it must be unwanted behaviour and therefore a bug?

Comment: I couldn't understand the question to be honest.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a copy of the PGF/Ti*k*Z manual, there is a section called **Key Management** containing everything you should know regarding these style stuff.

For example, You will immediately find that besides `.append style={}` there are also `prefix style={}` and `.add style={}{}`. The first two keys are just aliases of the third, as the names suggest.

Assume that you are quite familiar with key handlers. There is one more thing: `every foobar`.

They are many keys named as `every foobar` where `foobar` is some design element such as `picture`/`node`/`axis plot`/`mark`/etc. When and Where these key are applied depend on the package author. Most of the time we can only get very little hints by reviewing the source code.

Back to your code. your code is less unlikely to work because you have an `every` inside another `every`. Usually you only need one `every` because... well... that is **every**!! So by removing the outer layer of `every`, that is, put

<del>\pgfplotsset{</del>

```
\tikzset{
    every mark/.prefix style={
        mark color=none, solid, line join=miter, line width=0.5pt, mark size=2pt, mark repeat=100000
    }
}
```

then everything works fine.

## Edit

I am sorry I did not test it properly. It seems that `every mark` is a `tikz` key so it makes no sense to put it under `\pgfplotsset`.

By the way, the source code suggests that one can put `every mark` under `\pgfplotscreateplotcyclelist`. See `pgfplots.code.tex` line 242-308.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Symbol 1 but did you really try what you claim?
When I do as you suggest I can indeed overwrite the arguments I've been originally setting within `\pgfplotsset{every mark./...}` by placing those arguments within the `\addplot+[...]` arguments. But actually all arguments from the `\pgfplotsset{every mark./...}` are just ignored:
So if I don't specify anything within the `\addplot+[...]` arguments, the settings that I've been setting within `\pgfplotsset{every mark./...}` are just ignored and replaced by some defaults, e.g. `mark repeat=100000`is ignored.

Why is that?

Comment: @phw please check my update.

Comment: Thanks for your update, which is unfortunately still not solving the problem. Example: try to use `mark repeat=100000` within the `tikzset` command (as you suggested above) and then try to overwrite this setting with `mark repeat=1` within the `addplot+[...]` arguments. It won't work and the original setting (mark repeat=100000) will remain - which brings my problem back to the exact same situation as stated in my problem description...